# How can I progressively enhance country and state select fields?

Tags: javascript, ajax, html, progressive-enhancement

I haven't seen any website do this properly...

If I have two select fields, **country** and **state**, then I would code it like so:

```
<select name="country">
    <option>USA</option>
    <option>France</option>
</select>

<select name="state">
    <option></option>
</select>
```

I would then populate the state field using AJAX depending on the selection of the country.

However, this is the progressively enhanced state. How would it be done without the use of Javascript? and how should it be enhanced (if the previous example isn't the best way)?

Comment: What example. You have just posted two selects. What would _state_ contain for France? Do you have a static list of states of US? What does progressively enhanced mean? And what do you mean "Without JavaScript" - css? http://www.cssportal.com/css3-preview/showing-and-hiding-content-with-pure-css3.htm

Comment: You have to use JavaScript. It is called multicomboboxes

Comment: Here is a VERY simple CSS3 version based on the link I gave http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/c9M45/

Comment: First time I've heard of that, @jacktheripper. Any techniques on implementing this kind of form without JavaScript?

Comment: @jacktheripper: -1. Forms must never need JavaScript. And something simple as forms *is* always doable without js.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My recommendation is to have a submit button next / below the country drop down. When submitted the server will populate the state for the selected country and sends the response back.

Now, in your javascript on page load hide this button and attach on change handler to the country dropdown and make an AJAX call which will return the states.

So, if the javascript is disabled the button would perform the retrieval of the states. If enabled AJAX call would do the same.

Comment: What's the advantage of this approach versus the answer of Bergi (i.e. using optgroups)?

Comment: @zejesago You don't end up with a `select` with 10000 `option` elements.

Comment: @robertc Good point. Maybe I'm just lazy to do extra coding for a minority of users without JS. Haha.

Comment: @zejesago The issue you should be focusing on isn't making it available without JS, it's making it usable without JS (and/or without a mouse, and/or to seeing impaired).

Answer (score 1):

One solution could be to join the two selects together. Like

```
<select name="countryAndState">
    <option>USA - Alabama</option>
    <option>USA - Alaska</option>
    ...
    <option>France - Alsace</option>
    <option>France - Aquitaine</option>
</select>
```

or better

```
<select name="countryAndState">
    <optgroup label="USA">
         <option>Alabama</option>
         ...
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="France">
         <option>Alsace</option>
         ...
    </optgroup>
</select>
```

Of course, at least in the second form you will have to ensure that the option `value`s are unique. The [`optgroup element`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/the-optgroup-element.html) is the recommended way to group [select](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/the-select-element.html) options hierarchical in a tree order. That means, your enhancing javascript will also be able to extract the tree structure from DOM.

The other solution would be populating the state field server side, i.e. split your form up in two steps where one first selects the country, then the state. This could be done with a cookie or something to save the selected country; and whenever the submitted value for `country` differs from the saved value you need to output a new (unselected) state `select` element.

Comment: Yes, I think the optgroup thing is preferable against the stepped server-side solution, because you will be able to populate the JS structure with it.